# Compare multiple values in row to another row and output unmatched values - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare 4 values in one column on Sheet 1 (all in the same row) and see if those 4 values existing together in a row anywhere in another column on Sheet 2. If there isn't a match I want to extract 8 columns worth of data from Sheet 1 (columns CA:CH), and put it on Sheet 3.

So far I have only been able to compare one value at a time with the code below and can't figure out how to adjust it. I do have a lot of data to loop through so I was trying to avoid using an IF statement and incrementing through since that tends to go very slowly in my past experience.

```
    Sub CompareRowData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim lr2 As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range


    Set sh1 = Sheets("PreWork Tab")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("UR Facility Data")
    Set sh3 = Sheets("Missing Records")

lr1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = sh1.Range("CA2:CD" & lr1)
    For Each c In rng1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("B2:E" & lr2), c.Value) = 0 Then
            'I would like this to export the row data for columns CA through CH from sh1
            sh3.Range("A" & sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2) = c.Value
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: It's not too clear from your question exactly how your data is laid out and how you want to match - maybe try updating it with a few rows of sample data showing what a match would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used nested `for` loops, but i believe this won't slow down the process

```
Sub CompareRowData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim lr2 As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim check As String

    cnt = 2
    Set sh1 = Sheets("PreWork Tab")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("UR Facility Data")
    Set sh3 = Sheets("Missing Records")

    lr1 = sh1.UsedRange.Rows.count
    lr2 = sh2.UsedRange.Rows.count

    For i = 2 To lr1
        For j = 2 To lr2
            check = ""
            For k = 1 To 4
                If sh1.Cells(i, k + 78).Value <> sh2.Cells(j, k + 1).Value Then
                    check = "notfound"
                End If
            Next k
            If check = "" Then
                sh1.Range("CA" & i & ":CH" & i).Copy Destination:=sh3.Range("A" & cnt)
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```